# How to use popcorn.js to play webm videos on localhost?

Tags: javascript, webm, popcornjs

I have many .webm videos on my localhost when i'm trying to render it with popcorn.js they dont work until i use a video store on the net!
 I also tried with the official video from the popcorn.js homepage, localhost they dont work but calling it with an external url make it working!

How should i suppose to use and play .webm videos with popcorn.js on localhost?

I use firefox 10.0.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `http://127.0.0.1` as well instead of `http://localhost`?

If it's not working you can still edit your `hosts` file if you're under Windows.

The `hosts` file can be found here: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Add the following line to the end of the file:

`127.0.0.1 mycustomdomain`

Now try `http://mycustomdomain/`

Edit all your .webm links too to reflect the new address, eg.: `http://mycustomdomain/test.webm` or `http://127.0.0.1/test.webm`

Comment: Thanks papaiatis! i will give it a try!